# mutate_if - warning message

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello everybody,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("modelle") %>%
  mutate_if(~is.numeric(.x) & mean(.x) > 50, ~(.x / 1000))

Warning message:
In mean.default(.x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

This error seems to be because of the character vector. It works, but it´s still very ugly. Did I do anything wrong and what can be done better in that case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R does not short-circuit vectorized `&`, so this is running *both* `is.numeric` and `mean` on all columns. Since your first column (`modelle`) is obviously `character`, it is failing.

You actually don't need it to be vectorized, however. If you change from the vectorized `&` to the binary `&&`, R short-circuits it and you get the behavior you want.

```r
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("modelle") %>%
  mutate_if(~is.numeric(.x) && mean(.x) > 50, ~(.x / 1000)) %>%
  head()
#             modelle  mpg cyl  disp    hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6 0.160 0.110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 0.160 0.110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4 0.108 0.093 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 0.258 0.110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 0.360 0.175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6           Valiant 18.1   6 0.225 0.105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Further demonstration that `&` is not short-circuiting.

```r
mymean <- function(x, ...) {
  if (is.character(x)) {
    message("character?")
    return(Inf) # this is certainly not the right thing to do in general ...
  } else mean(x, ...)
}
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("modelle") %>%
  mutate_if(~is.numeric(.x) & mymean(.x) > 50, ~(.x / 1000)) %>%
  head()
# character?
#             modelle  mpg cyl  disp    hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6 0.160 0.110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 0.160 0.110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4 0.108 0.093 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 0.258 0.110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 0.360 0.175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6           Valiant 18.1   6 0.225 0.105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

If short-circuiting *were* taking place, then `mymean` would never get to the message. (I don't think this `mymean` is a viable replacement here, for a couple of reasons: (1) the use of `Inf` was solely to ensure the condition *outside* of the call to `mean` worked, but if an error/warning occurs and a `numeric` is expected, then one should typically return `NA` or `NaN`, not a number ... even if you might not consider `Inf` a real usable number. (2) It is addressing a *symptom*, not the *problem*. The problem is the absence of short-circuiting in vectorized logical expressions.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use "&&" instead of "&". The first is used for scalars and the second, for vectors. In your case, the average is a scalar.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
mtcars %>%
rownames_to_column("modelle") %>%
mutate_if(~is.numeric(.x) && mean(.x) > 50, ~(.x / 1000))
```

Comment: That's not technically correct: `&` will happily work with scalars as well, just try `T & T`. The issue is with short-circuiting.